# What is a relatively bound variable?

Tags: logic, terminology, proof-theory

**edit:** Interestingly, the authors also state at one point that the choice of introduction rule is determined by the structure of the *previous* goal and the list of introduction rules; but at another point, that the choice of introduction rule is determined by the structure of the *current* goal and the list of introduction rules. I believe the latter is correct, but I'll have to be more careful implementing the paper's algorithm than I previously thought.

In any case, I believe the "no variable can relatively bind itself" restriction intends to preclude abstraction on a variable using that variable, but I could be wrong. If anything rests on whether or not this is correct, I'll attempt to contact the authors.

**original:** In a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.977&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on natural deduction proof search, the authors write that the free variables $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n$ occurring in the formulae $\forall \alpha.\phi(\alpha,\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n)$ and $\exists \alpha . \phi(\alpha,\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n)$ in the conclusions of the quantifier introduction rules
$$\frac{\phi(\alpha/\beta,\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n)}{\forall \alpha . \phi(\alpha,\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n)} \quad (\forall\text{-in})$$
and 
$$\frac{\phi(\alpha/t)}{\exists \alpha . \phi (\alpha,\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n)}\quad(\exists\text{-in})$$
are *relatively flagged* or *bound*. Presumably, then, a variable is relatively bound if and only if it occurs free in the conclusion of a quantifier introduction rule. However, in defining a natural deduction derivation and presenting algorithms, they remark that no variable may *relatively bind* itself. For instance, they require that unification not produce substitutions causing variables to relatively bind themselves.

I searched through several logic books I had lying around, especially ones focusing on automated reasoning, but couldn't find a definition of relatively bound variables. Has anyone encountered this term before? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: I apologize if this seems too obvious of a thing to do, but... since they provided it, have you e-mailed any of the authors with this question?

Comment: If anything ends up resting on the definition of the term, I'll contact the authors. I assume, however, that spending more time with the paper should allow me to deduce its meaning. Thanks for the suggestion, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper actually says "relatively bounded", not "bound", but since it also says "relatively binds itself", not "relatively bounds itself", this seems to be a mistake. A definition of these terms is found in [Section 3.3 of this paper](http://books.google.com/books?id=_5olEPwX1VkC&lpg=PA62&ots=CNOAENZ8LL&dq=%22relatively%20bound%22&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q=%22relatively%20bound%22&f=false), which is by mostly the same authors and contains the same apparent mistake.